# Xampp local Drupal install image path problems

Tags: drupal, xampp

I've got Drupal 6.19 installed locally in a xampp SUBDIRECTORY. Everything works great with the exception of the images are broken. The path being created is missing my subdirectory where Drupal is installed.

The path should start with:

http://localhost/drupal6.19/sites/default/files/

but is instead
http://localhost/sites/default/files.

I've tried setting base url in the setting php file and clearing my cache:

`$base_url = 'http://localhost/drupal6.19';`

did not work. I've also tried uncommenting this line in the htaccess file and clearing cache:

`# RewriteBase /drupal6.19`

nothing.

I'm running out of ideas. Any help?

I won't do a clean install as I've already spent a lot of time migrating content over and configuring the site. I need to get this fixed somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Have you changes something in the hosts file. Its located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc. The content of the file look like

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```